# How can I prove that the median is a nonlinear function?

Tags: median

My question flows out of [the top answer to this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/232042/9162), from which I learned that a "linear function" is any function $f$ with properties of additivity and homogeneity of degree 1:

$$
f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)  \\
f(ax) = af(x)
$$

Just reflecting on the formula for the median it seems to me that the function does not have additivity, but does have homogeneity of degree 1. Am I right about this? How can I prove what the right answer is?

Comment: To prove something is *not* true, finding a counterexample tends to be the easiest method.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

#### Median is homogenous of degree 1

Let $a$ be a real scalar and $\mathbf{x}$ be a vector in $\mathcal{R}^n$. Let us number the elements of $\mathbf{x}$ in order so that $x_1 \leq x_2 \leq \ldots \leq x_n $. 
Let $x_m = f(\mathbf{x})$ be the median of $\mathbf{x}$.

Observe that for $a \geq 0$, the elements of the vector $a\mathbf{x}$ have the same order:
$$ a x_1  \leq \ldots \leq a x_m \leq \ldots \leq a x_n $$
And for $a < 0$ the order is reversed:
$$ a x_n  \leq \ldots \leq a x_m \leq \ldots \leq a x_1 $$
In either case $ax_m$ is in the middle, it's the median.

### Median violates additivity

Counterexample to additivity:
$$\mathbf{x} = \left[\begin{array}{c}2 \\ 4 \\ 6 \end{array} \right] \quad \quad \mathbf{y} = \left[\begin{array}{c} 0 \\ -4 \\ 4 \end{array}\right] \quad \quad \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{y} = \left[\begin{array}{c} 2 \\ 0 \\ 10 \end{array}\right] $$

$$ f(\mathbf{x}) = 4\quad \quad f(\mathbf{y}) = 0 \quad \quad f(\mathbf{x} + \mathbf{y}) = 2$$

---

Pedantic subpoint: if all the elements of both $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are in ascending (or descending) order, then the median does satisfy additivity.

Comment: Another pedantic comment: the same if either $x$ or $y$ are constant, or $x_i \ll y_i$, or $y_i \ll x_i$ for all $i$.

Comment: (+1) Re the pedantic subpoint: the set of vectors in ascending or descending order does not however form a vector space, so the concept of linear mapping is perhaps not so appropriate.

Comment: @JuhoKokkala Yeah, if $\mathcal{A}$  is the set of vectors in ascending order and $\mathbf{x} \in \mathcal{A}$, the additive inverse $-\mathbf{x}$ doesn't belong to $\mathcal{A}$. That requirement of a vector space is violated.

Comment: @JuhoKokkala As long as + and negation are defined consistently (i.e. the vectors are reordered after being negated) then I don't see why this wouldn't be a vector space. It looks like all the axioms of a vector space hold.

Answer (score 6):

The OP is correct -- median is not linear since additivity does not hold, but homogeneity of degree $1$ holds.

#### Additivity does not hold

We show by counterexample that the additivity does not hold: let $x=(0,1,2)$ and $y=(2,0,0)$ and let $f$ be the mapping from a vector to the median of its elements. Now, $f(x)=1,~f(y)=0$, so, 
\begin{equation}
f(x+y) = f((2,1,2)) = 2 \neq 1 = f(x) + f(y).
\end{equation}

#### Homogeneity of degree 1 holds

The homogeneity of degree $1$ indeed holds as postulated in the answer:multiplying by a scalar does not change the order (except by reversing it if the scalar is negative, but this does not change who is in the middle), so if the median of $x$ is $x_i$, then also the median of $a\,x$ is $a\,x_i$. For even number of elements, the reasoning works if the median is defined to be the average of the two middle elements.

Answer (score 3):

First, [median minimizes the absolute error](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163388/l2-regularization-is-equivalent-to-gaussian-prior/163413#163413) (Hurley, 2009) and [$\mathrm{abs}$ is not a linear function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/88669/is-the-absolute-value-function-a-linear-function).

As about $\alpha f(x) = f(\alpha x)$, there can be two interpretations depending on if you ask about case where $\alpha$ is a scalar, or a vector. Let's consider both cases, but first recall that we calculate median by sorting the values and taking the middle one.

1. **If $\alpha$ is a scalar** (as implied by the definition), then $\alpha f(x) = f(\alpha x)$ holds since multiplying $x$ by a scalar *does not change* the ordering.
2. **If $\alpha$ is a vector**, then taken at face value it doesn't have much sense since median is a function that maps $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, as noticed by *@JuhoKokkala*. In such case we only can re-phrase your question to comparing multiplying vectors and then sorting, versus sorting and then multiplying. In such case, the ordering of elements in $x\alpha$ *may be different* then ordering of $x$. So in both cases you may take different $x_i$ multiplied by $\alpha_i$ as your median.

You can easily produce numerical examples to convince yourself about that:

```r
set.seed(123)

N <- 51
x <- rnorm(N)
a <- runif(N)

(x*a)[order(x*a)][(N+1)/2]         # multiply and then sort
(x[order(x)]*a[order(x)])[(N+1)/2] # sort and then multiply
```

It is similar for $f(xy) = f(x) + f(y)$, where $x$ and $y$ are vectors, since sum of the elements *may change* the ordering (again, this is very simple to check numerically).

---

Hurley, W. J. (2009) [An Inductive Approach to Calculate the MLE for the Double Exponential Distribution.](http://digitalcommons.wayne.edu/jmasm/vol8/iss2/25/) Journal of Modern Applied Statistical Methods: 8(2), Article 25.

Comment: I don't understand how this is related to linearity of median, or how the componentwise product $x\,\alpha$ would at all occur in considerations about linearity. Instead, the argument would work if one replaced the product by summation.

Comment: I do not understand what the construction $x\alpha$ has to do with the question. Is the question about something else than whether the median (as a mapping from a list of observations to the value of the median) is a linear function $\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Um, no, that $a$ is a scalar.

Comment: The question links to this definition: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_map#Definition_and_first_consequences also OP didn't mention, nor comment that $\alpha$ is a scalar... EDIT: added notice about it in my answer.

Comment: But the definition you linked to says that $\alpha$ is a scalar - -and without mentioning anything one would assume that "linear function" refers to the commonly used definition of linear function. Furthermore since $f$ maps to scalars, if $a$ was a vector, the LHS would be a scalar and the RHS a vector, so the equality would not even make sense.

Comment: @JuhoKokkala You are right, taken at face value if the function maps $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ it does not make sens. However this is the only interpretation possible *if* $\alpha$ is considered as a vector -- and this is how I understood the question (and the answer was accepted so my understanding appeared to be valid).

Comment: Do you have any  source for a definition of "linear function" where that $\alpha$ would be a vector? As far as I know, this answer is based on inventing a new meaning for the term "linear function"  (I suppose the answer was accepted due to  OP not fully understanding the definition of linear function).

Comment: No, it says $\alpha$ is a scalar (read the first line "Let V and W..."). The second paragraph ("This is equivalent...") just says that the two conditions imply that any linear combination can be decomposed (by decomposing all of the multiple multiplications of a vector by a scalar and the  multiple summations of two vectors). Do you understand that in the Eq. below second paragraph each $x_i$ is a _vector_ while each $a_i$ is a scalar (So it's not like a dot product or a elementwise product of two vectors)?